# How to Deploy our Customize Thingsboard to Kubenetes Engine?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-health-check, thingsboard

After make docker image of cassandra, cassandra-setup, application and zookeeper from my custom thingsboard.
I tried to deploy that to Kubernetes Engine, there's no error, but not running well.

Here is my command for yaml from my github:

```
curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Firdauzfan/ThingsboardGSPE/master/docker/k8s/common.yaml > common.yaml

curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Firdauzfan/ThingsboardGSPE/master/docker/k8s/cassandra.yaml > cassandra.yaml

curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Firdauzfan/ThingsboardGSPE/master/docker/k8s/zookeeper.yaml > zookeeper.yaml

curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Firdauzfan/ThingsboardGSPE/master/docker/k8s/tb.yaml > tb.yaml

curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Firdauzfan/ThingsboardGSPE/master/docker/k8s/cassandra-setup.yaml > cassandra-setup.yaml
```

and here is my docker image:
https://hub.docker.com/u/firdauzfanani/

Example: when i run command kubectl create -f cassandra.yaml, cassandra engine just show running but not ready.

[Status screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXmaB.jpg)

Comment: Hi, have you been able to solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

**If** it is shown as `not ready` even if it is running with no issue (es: you can `ssh` into it and all the services are running), could be an misconfiguration of your redinessprobe that I see defined in the YAML file as follow, but I have no clue regarding its behaviour. Consider that [accordingly](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-probes/#define-readiness-probes) to documentation it should return 0.

```
readinessProbe:
          exec:
            command:
            - /bin/bash
            - -c
            - /ready-probe.sh
```

**On the other hand**, if when you try to access the pod you face some kind of errors, I would suggest you if you didn't do it already to retrieve further information to carry on the troubleshooting running the following commands:

```
$ kubectl describe deployments
$ kubectl describe pods
$ kubectl describe services
```

This series of commands could help you in order to understand better what is going on.

Please run them and edit your initial post with the output and I can take a look to them.

To `ssh` into the pod run:

```
$ kubectl get pods (to retrieve pod name)
$ kubectl exec -ti PODNAME  /bn/bash
```

**UPDATE**
I deployed your YAML files, the pods is running correctly (I believe) what is failing is the probe whose content is the following:

```
cat /ready-probe.sh
if [[ $(nodetool status | grep $POD_IP) == *"UN"* ]]; then
  if [[ $DEBUG ]]; then
    echo "UN";
  fi
  exit 0;
else
  if [[ $DEBUG ]]; then
    echo "Not Up";
  fi
  exit 1;
```